# Is there a name for sand-clay mixture?

Tags: terminology, material-identification, clay

Is there a name for the mixture you get upon mixing sand and clay together? As from what I believe, you use something like it in sand casting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clay-sand mixture used in casting is known as **green sand**, **foundry sand**, or **molding sand**.

> Green sand is an aggregate of sand, bentonite clay, pulverized coal and water. Its principal use is in making molds for metal casting.
>   <sub>via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molding_sand)</sub>

Different proportions of sand, clay, and other compounds [result in slightly different properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sand_casting#Green_sand), but green sand can be packed tightly to hold its shape and therefore not move when molten metal is poured into a mold.

A walkthrough of the sand casting process can be found at [Foundry 101: Step-by-Step Sand Casting Instructions](http://foundry101.com/new_page_7.htm).